# Obtaining FCM User Tokens for Push Notifications Despite Browser Notification Permission Restrictions

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I would like to know the steps and documentation for sending in-app notifications via FCM. My client is built using React, the server uses Express, and FCM is the chosen notification service.

The issue I'm encountering is that FCM refuses to provide me with the user token if the browser has not granted permission for notifications from the website. In this scenario, I'm unable to send the token to the server for push notifications. I would like FCM to generate a token regardless of whether browser notifications are enabled.

Now, my question is how can I generate a token and send push notifications without relying on browser permissions?

Use case:

I have a website that requires an app notification system without relying on browser notifications. For example, if someone likes a Facebook post, they receive a notification within the app's notification section. Similarly, I want FCM to provide me with notifications about the status of my blog when someone likes it. I do not want to depend on browser notifications for this notification system.

I read docs and followed to generate token and send push notification via FCM online tool. But this does not meet my requirement, tried to disable browser notification permission it doesn't give me token. This is valid for push notification service but i want to send data message within application as per usecase described above.